# custom Pagination with A-Z Sorting Filters

Tags: visualforce, controller, pagination

How to create a custom pagination with a-z filter without using standardsetcontroller.

explaination-
1) I want to display few fields(name,city etc)  of all contacts records on the vf page with any pagesize with next and previous button on it.

2) It should also have all Alphabets on the top as commandlink or anything, whenever i click on any letter it should show me all the contact records whose name start with this letter.for eg. If a click on 'A' it should show all records whose name starts with a like 'Anthony'.

3) by default the page should show all records with any pagesize

4)and next and previous should also work in case of a-z filter

Comment: What did you try so far, there are lot of blog posts available for pagination.
This post might serve your requirement http://www.davehelgerson.com/?p=549

Comment: Actually i tried doing it by my own but it doesn't work! Anyway this one looks more promising .Thank you for your help! Really appreciate that.

Answer (score -1):

**Apex code:**

```
public class ContactListViewController {
public ContactlistViewController(){
    RecordsPerPageslist=10;
}
list<contact> con = [SELECT Name,Account.name,Title,Phone,Email FROM Contact]; 
public list<String> alphabet{
    get{                                                                                                                    //To display a list of alphabets on vf page 
        alphabet = new list<string>{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','Others','All'};
            return alphabet;         
            }
    set;
}
public String alphaSearchConct{get;set;}                                                    // To get commandlink parameter for alphabet selected
public Pagereference getalphaSearch(){                                                              //To update contact list as per the alphabet selected by the user

    if (alphaSearchConct=='All'){
        con = [SELECT name,Account.name,Title,Phone,Email FROM contact];
    }
    else{
            con = [SELECT name,Account.name,Title,Phone,Email FROM contact WHERE lastName Like:alphaSearchConct+'%'];
    }
    ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(con);
    stdSetController= ssc;
    return null;
}      
public Integer PageNumber{
    get{                                                            //To get current page number
        this.PageNumber=stdSetController.getPageNumber();
        return this.PageNumber;
    }
    set{                                                              // To navigate to the page number entered by the user
        stdSetController.setPageNumber(value);
    }
}
public Integer TotalPages{                                            // Total number of pages as per user selection of Records per page
    get{
          if(stdSetController.getResultSize() <=10)
              this.TotalPages=1;
        if(Math.Mod(stdSetController.getResultSize() ,stdSetController.getPageSize()) == 0)
            this.TotalPages =(stdSetController.getResultSize()/stdSetController.getPageSize());
        else
            this.TotalPages = (stdSetController.getResultSize()/stdSetController.getPageSize())+1;
        System.Debug(this.TotalPages);
        return totalpages;
    }
    set;
}
public Integer MaxNumberOfRecords{                                    //Maximum number of records in a query list
    get{
             return stdSetController.getRecords().size();
    }
    set;
}
public list<SelectOption> getRecordsPerPageOptionList(){              //To display a drop down list on vf page  
        list<SelectOption>  options = new list<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new selectOption('10','10'));
        options.add(new selectOption('25','25'));
        options.add(new selectOption('50','50'));
        options.add(new selectOption('100','100'));
        options.add(new selectOption('200','200'));
        return options;
}
public Integer RecordsPerPageslist{ 
    get;set{                                                          //To select number of records per page
       // System.debug(value);
        if(value!=null){
            this.RecordsPerPagesList=value;
        }
       // else
          // this.RecordsPerPageslist=10;
    }       
}
public void next(){
    this.stdSetController.next();
}
public ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetController{            //Instantiating a standard set controller
    get{
        if(stdSetController==null){
             stdSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(con);
        }
          stdSetController.setPageSize(RecordsPerPageslist);        //Limiting Number of records to be displayed per page 
           return stdSetController;   
    }
    set;
}
public list<contact> getcontactList(){                               //to display records on vf page
   return (list<contact>)stdSetController.getRecords();
}
```

}

**VisualForce code:**

```
    <apex:page controller="ContactListViewController" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
<!-- For alphabetic search-->
<div align="right">
        <apex:panelGrid >
            <apex:repeat value="{!alphabet}" var="alph">
                <apex:commandLink value="{!alph} | " action="{!getalphaSearch}" reRender="table">
                <apex:param name="a" value="{!alph}" assignTo="{!alphaSearchConct}"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:repeat>
        </apex:panelGrid>
    </div>
<apex:PageBlock id="table">
    <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!ContactList}" var="contacts" >
    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!contacts.id}">
        {!contacts.name}
        </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!contacts.account.id}">
            {!contacts.account.name}
        </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!contacts.Title}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!contacts.Phone}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!contacts.email}"/>
    <apex:inlineEditSupport />
    </apex:PageBlockTable>
    <!-- below code for pagination -->
    <div align = "center" id="button">
           <!-- To return to first page of records-->
           <apex:commandButton action="{!stdSetController.first}" value="<<" title="First Page" disabled="{!!stdSetController.HasPrevious}" reRender="table,button"/>
           <!-- To return to Previous page of records-->
           <apex:commandButton action="{!stdSetController.previous}" value="Previous" disabled="{!!stdSetController.HasPrevious}" reRender="table,button"/>
           <!-- To return to next page of records-->
           <apex:commandButton action="{!stdSetController.next}" value="Next >" disabled = "{!!stdSetController.HasNext}" reRender="table,button"/>
           <!-- To return to last page of records-->
            <apex:commandButton action="{!stdSetController.last}" value=">>" title="Last Page" disabled="{!!stdSetController.HasNext}" reRender="table,button"/>
           <!-- InputText to display current page and to navigate to any page number, At righmost side of page-->
           <span style="float:right">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Page ">
                </apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:InputText value="{!PageNumber}" maxLength="4" size="1"/>
                <!-- To navigate to the page-->           
                <apex:outputLabel value=" of {!TotalPages}">
                </apex:outputLabel>
            </span>
            <!-- To display a list for number of records to be selected per page-->
            <span style = "float:left">
                <apex:SelectList value="{!RecordsPerPageslist}" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecordsPerPageOptionList}">    
                    </apex:selectOptions>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="table"/>
                </apex:SelectList>
            </span>
            </div>

</apex:PageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
<apex:page controller="ContactListViewController" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
<!-- For alphabetic search-->
<div align="right">
        <apex:panelGrid >
            <apex:repeat value="{!alphabet}" var="alph">
                <apex:commandLink value="{!alph} | " action="{!getalphaSearch}" reRender="table">
                <apex:param name="a" value="{!alph}" assignTo="{!alphaSearchConct}"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:repeat>
        </apex:panelGrid>
    </div>
<apex:PageBlock id="table">
    <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!ContactList}" var="contacts" >
    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!contacts.id}">
        {!contacts.name}
        </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!contacts.account.id}">
            {!contacts.account.name}
        </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!contacts.Title}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!contacts.Phone}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!contacts.email}"/>
    <apex:inlineEditSupport />
    </apex:PageBlockTable>
    <!-- below code for pagination -->
    <div align = "center" id="button">
           <!-- To return to first page of records-->
           <apex:commandButton action="{!stdSetController.first}" value="<<" title="First Page" disabled="{!!stdSetController.HasPrevious}" reRender="table,button"/>
           <!-- To return to Previous page of records-->
           <apex:commandButton action="{!stdSetController.previous}" value="Previous" disabled="{!!stdSetController.HasPrevious}" reRender="table,button"/>
           <!-- To return to next page of records-->
           <apex:commandButton action="{!stdSetController.next}" value="Next >" disabled = "{!!stdSetController.HasNext}" reRender="table,button"/>
           <!-- To return to last page of records-->
            <apex:commandButton action="{!stdSetController.last}" value=">>" title="Last Page" disabled="{!!stdSetController.HasNext}" reRender="table,button"/>
           <!-- InputText to display current page and to navigate to any page number, At righmost side of page-->
           <span style="float:right">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Page ">
                </apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:InputText value="{!PageNumber}" maxLength="4" size="1"/>
                <!-- To navigate to the page-->           
                <apex:outputLabel value=" of {!TotalPages}">
                </apex:outputLabel>
            </span>
            <!-- To display a list for number of records to be selected per page-->
            <span style = "float:left">
                <apex:SelectList value="{!RecordsPerPageslist}" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecordsPerPageOptionList}">    
                    </apex:selectOptions>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="table"/>
                </apex:SelectList>
            </span>
            </div>

</apex:PageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation, a code dump without one does not prove very useful for other users, who might try copy pasting without really understanding what is going on, which may lead to other questions on the forum. Thanks